# BIDS "Start Debugging" button not working

Tags: ssis, bids

This is a very strange issue.  In BIDS/Visual Studio, the "Start Debugging" button does not run the active package that I am working on.  Instead it opens another package in the project (always the same one) and runs that one instead.  I can only run the active package by right clicking on it in Solution Explorer and selecting "Execute Package".  I run BIDS on three separate machines and the other two machines do not do this.  Is this button programmable?  I have not found any setting for this button.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 6):

In your Project Properties (right click on the project), under the Debugging tab you should have an option for setting a StartObjectID. By Default, this is `<Active Package>` but if you have an actual package selected here, then that would correlate with the behaviour you are describing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this.
open a new ssis project,then import this package which is not debugging into the project.

steps.
create new project->SSIS packages->right click->add existing packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right-click the package you want to use as the main package and set it up to be the starting project. Right-click the package in Solution Explorer and select "Set as StartUp Object" from the menu.